How do you align images to the left when exporting org mode to latex?
I can't find a way to align images to the left when exporting org mode file to pdf. They always end up in the middle or :float option makes them "float", but if there is more than one image they will get put in the same row. I'm just trying to align them to the left (one image per row).
e.g. this image:
#+attr_org: :width 400px
#+attr_latex: :width 10cm
[[./images/image17.png]] 

will display in the middle and I can't find a way to align it left
headers file: https://pastebin.com/9nYe45bP
headers in org mode document:
#+LATEX_HEADER: \input{/home/<USER>/latex/headers.tex}
#+OPTIONS: \n:t
#+OPTIONS: H:6
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil
#+LATEX_COMPILER: xelatex

export command: emacsclient --eval '(progn (find-file "<file-name>.org") (org-latex-export-to-pdf))'

Set the :center property to `nil:
#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 10cm :center nil

The point is that, uncharacteristically, Org mode insists on putting images in a center environment by default, so any LaTeX setup you do to make them flush left is probably  going to be ineffective: you need to tell Org mode not to use a center environment. See Images in LaTeX export in the manual:

The LaTeX export backend centers all images by default.  Setting
‘:center’ to ‘nil’ disables centering.  To disable centering globally,
set ‘org-latex-images-centered’ to ‘nil’.

In addition, if the image begins a paragraph, LaTeX will give it the standard paragraph indent (unless it's the first paragraph in a section)1. If you want it flush left, the usual workaround for that is to add \noindent to the beginning of the paragraph:
#+LATEX: \noindent
#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 10cm :center nil

For inline image display, you also need to set org-image-actual-width to nil in order for #+ATTR_ORG to be effective. See the doc string of the variable (C-h v org-image-actual-width)2:

When set to nil, first try to get the width from #+ATTR_ORG.  If
that is not found, use the first #+ATTR_xxx :width specification.
If that is also not found, fall back on the original image width.


Footnotes:
[1]  That's assuming that no modification has been made to \parindent, but of course, you have made such a modification in your init file, so the following does not apply to you, but I include it here for the rest of us.
[2] The preceding sentence is not quite right: the doc string explains that setting it to nil is the simplest possibility but it can also be set to a single-element list where the element is a number that specifies the desired width. See the doc string for all the gory details and, if you are like me, be prepared to re-read it every time you need it - I find it impossible to remember all the ramifications.

Thank you, that is very helpful. Did you mean (setq org-image-actual-width '(600)) instead of org-display-image-width? I couldn't find org-display-image-width in my emacs, but the org-image-actual-width seemed to work, although it still got overriden by +#attr_latex: :width, so I still needed to set +#attr_org :width over every image.

Yes, sorry - I will fix the name.
